# How to update List of string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm doing a course on PluralSight but the code in the course is not complete and there is a quickedit IActionResult that I can't seem to figure out.

In my View I have the code below:

```
@model IList<string>
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    <form asp-action="QuickEdit" method="post">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Soup name @(i + 1);</label>
            <input id="soupNames" name="soupNames" asp-for="@Model[i]" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        }
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
}
else
{
    <h2>No Soups in the system</h2>
}
```

The Controller:

```
public IActionResult QuickEdit()
{
    var soupNames = _soupRepository.AllSoups.Select(s => s.SoupName).ToList();
    return View(soupNames);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult QuickEdit(List<string> soups)
{
    var soupNames = _soupRepository.AllSoups.Select(s => s.SoupName).ToList();


    for (var i = 0; i < soupNames.Count; i++)
    {
        soupNames[i] = soups[i];
     }
    return View(soups);
}
```

Could someone help me out?
I want the values passed through replace the original values when I click the update button.

Comment: What you posted returns the input (soups) only, not the loaded data. It doesn't *edit* anything either, it just replaces the loaded names. The stored names are unchanged

Comment: Every Pluralsight course has a "Discussion" area where you can ask questions  about the course of code, this would be a good place to ask for your current issue.

Comment: @KarenPayne That was the first place I checked but the course is outdated. I already had to do a lot of research to update the code from asp.net core 1.1 to 3.1 but this was clearly a lack of knowledge on my end

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know, I first want to make sure that the values I get back are the correct ones before hooking it up to the repo and saving it to the db

Comment: @Samuel8000 an ASP.NET Core 1.0 course is *not* appropriate for ASP.NET Core 3. There have been a lot of changes since. Pluralsight authors update their courses regularly though (that's how they make money), so you'll easily find courses for ASP.NET Core 3.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know, he renewed the first part of the course for 3.0 but the interesting part (building enterprise apps) not. The concepts of the course are interesting and I'm not to lazy to do some research. 

Concerning my question, Could I ask you how you would save that data to a database using EF Core? I'm stuck on that one too (still learning)

Comment: If you use EF Core you don't need a repository or Unit of work. A DbContext *is* a Unit of work and a DbSet *is* a repository. All you need to save all changes made during a DbContext's lifetime is to call `thatContext.SaveChanges`. That's how you get UoW too - if you *don't* make that call, no changes are saved. That's why "generic repository"
 is an antipattern when used on top of any ORM

Comment: That's why you'll see DbContexts used with `using` blocks all the time - the DbContext specifies a UnitOfWork that lives only inside the `using` block. If `SaveChanges` isn't called before exiting the `using` block, all changes are discarded. There's no need for explicit transactions this way. `SaveChanges` already uses a transaction internally to ensure changes are all-or-nothing.

Comment: This way DbContext doesn't even have to maintain an open connection until you actually call `SaveChanges` or load data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line

```
<input id="soupNames" name="soupNames" asp-for="@Model[i]" class="form-control"/>
```

need to change to something like

```
<input id="@(i)_soups" name="[@(i)].soups" asp-for="@Model[i]" class="form-control"/>
```

you need to google model binding lists

try , it may show you the raw syntax so you can change to just input

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => @Model[i] )
```

Comment: If I change it to  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => @Model[i] ) it works

Comment: @Samuel8000 you can now see how it put the names in the html.... then u  could manually do it...